# Swift 4: Convert any number value to 100%

Tags: ios, swift, geometry

I am working on a piece of code that needs to calculate area on a `UIView`. I need to be able to take a `UIView` and determine the amount of space available to place `UI` controls. So whatever the width of the `UIView` is, maybe it is 724pt, I need to convert that value to equal 100%. The trick here is the value in which I am retreiving the width of the `UIView` is of type `Int`. This value will be representative of the number of points the `UIView` being calculated takes up in relation to it's superview, but I am being asked to convert this into a `CGFloat` that represents the percentage of *negative* space remaining within the `UIView`'s superview at either the right most bound, left most bound, or both of it's superview. So, if I wanted to separate out the view out by half, I would just take 100% (724) and say return 50% for the width of half (362pt). This would need to be converted into a `CGFloat` from an `Int`.

What I am looking for is the formula on how to achieve this in Swift 4.

Comment: That's not Swift, that's geometry. For two dimensions, which a view's frame is, it's width times height (square points?). If the view's width is 724, then 724 **is** 100%. Add up the subview widths, subtract their total from 724, and what remains is what you have unused. Thus, if your subviews total 362, you have 50% used, leaving 50% left. I'm obviously missing something. What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make it this complicated.

If you want 50% of the view's width then simply do:

```
let halfWidth = someView.frame.width * 0.5
```

Replace 0.5 with whatever percentage you need.

Comment: @LeoDabus `midX` does not give half the width, it gives the location of the middle of the frame. For a frame with x of 100 and width of 300, midX would be 250 while width * 0.5 is obviously 150.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's a special case. And the question seems to give 50% as just one example.

Comment: Thanks for the response @rmaddy. As simple as it seems I believe you are on the right track. And this is probably because my mind is wrapped up like a pretzel now thinking about this and the solution escapes me. If my requirement to layout a complicated piece of UI didn't involve doing it all in code and still handle orientation change, I would use auto layout and be done with this. But I was never great at geometry. And I do apologize for the quickly written question. It didn't seem to fully explain my somewhat complex and difficult question to describe. I edited my question.

Comment: Sorry but your updated question is less clear than the original and my answer still seems to apply. What about my answer doesn't answer your updated question?

Comment: In essence your answer does answer my question. There is just some manual work I'll need to do with this "so-called" multiplication. I really was just making this overly complicated.